# How to declare and set a ListBox variable in Excel VBA?

Tags: forms, excel, listbox, vba

Struggling to find any info on how to refer to a listbox in a worksheet (using MS Forms reference) from within a module (not a worksheet or form) in Excel.

```
Dim lb As MSForms.ListBox
Dim chartSheet as worksheet

    Set chartSheet = Sheets("Chart")

    Set lb = chartSheet.Objects("lbPartNo") ' nope
    Set lb = chartSheet.ListObjects("lbPartNo") ' nope
    Set lb = chartSheet.ListBoxes("lbPartNo") ' nope
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's actually an MSForms.Listbox (i.e. ActiveX) then:

```
Set lb = chartSheet.lbPartNo
```

Otherwise, declare it as just `Listbox` and use:

```
 Set lb = chartSheet.ListBoxes("lbPartNo")
```

Comment: Ah OK, I was confusing plain old listboxes with the library for the ActiveX control. Thanks a bunch.